# Is there a way to automatically reinstall packages that were "installed by an R version with different internals"?

Tags: r

I've just upgraded from `R 3.5.3` to `R 3.6.0`, and (as you might expect) I have been encountering the dreaded:

```
package {package_name} was installed by an R version with different internals; 
it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
```

Removing/reinstalling each offending package often results in the same error popping-up for one or more dependencies, and the entire recursive procedure can take several hours to resolve. A Google search (indeed,  searching StackOverflow) confirms that this is a common issue for people.

Is there some way of saying to R:

> If you come across a package that was installed by an R version with different internals, just remove/reinstall it automatically?

Comment: Have you thought about using Rstudio and installing/upgrading packages using the interface in the bottom right frame?

Comment: You could just reinstall everything.

Comment: See `?update.packages`

Comment: [From the FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What_0027s-the-best-way-to-upgrade_003f): `update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Alexis -- that worked perfectly! If you add this as an answer, then I'll up-vote it. (Also, thanks Paul and Hong for your suggestions)